# Is it possible to set cookie as custom header while using Push option in libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp, libgit2sharp-ssh

In my project I have a requirement where I need to set cookie in the http header before calling Push command.I saw an option present to add custom header in FetchOptions class, but could not see in PushOption.Please confirm if adding cookie in header is allowed?

I saw an option present to add custom header in FetchOptions class, but could not see in PushOption

================================================================
Update:

This option is enabled in the latest release
https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/releases/tag/0.28.0
Thank you @bording@gmail.com for this release